# If I have an IR source, would glass lenses work in focusing them at a point?

Tags: lenses, infrared-radiation

So I'm using near-infrared light of the wavelength of order 700-800 nm. I need it focused at one point. I was wondering if using glass lenses would do the job or not?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, they would work, I've done it myself.

Comment: ok @MichaelWalsby . Two follow-up questions. First, are there some limits of the lens to be used? like the thickness of the lens and so on.
Second, what can I do to make sure the lens that I'm working with actually bends infrared light?

Comment: The issue is that normal glass is not very transparent to IR.  As focusing, it works, but may absorb most of your light. For your 700-800nm semms to have no problems. See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74638/transmittance-of-glass

Comment: Why not take some lenses and use an infra-red lamp or an electric fire as an infrared  source, and focus the rays on the back of your hand? When it begins to hurt, that is a sign the infrared is being focussed, and the lense which hurts most of all is the best one to use.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby, that's a good point, but the issue is that I need the source and lens to be very small...

Comment: @patta, that's a good lead to start. Thanks :)

Comment: patta's link seems to indicate that at 700-800nm Michael Walsby's answer is correct